# Avoid send telemetry data for response code 2xx and 3xx to Azure application insight

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-application-insights

from my Angular application, i want to avoid send telemetry data for response code range between 2xx and 3xx  ( DO NOT INDEX THEM ), for that i implement this code but those logs appears anyway in my AI logs!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationInsights, IExceptionTelemetry } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApplicationInsightsService {
  private appInsights : ApplicationInsights;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
      config: {
        instrumentationKey: `${environment.applicationInsights.instrumentationKey}`
      }
    });
    this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
    this.loadCustomTelemetryProperties();
    this.createRouterSubscription();
  }
  setUserId(userId: string) {
    this.appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext(userId);
  }
  clearUserId() {
    this.appInsights.clearAuthenticatedUserContext();
  }
  logPageView(name?: string, uri?: string) {
    this.appInsights.trackPageView({ name, uri});
  }
  logException(error : Error){
    let exception : IExceptionTelemetry = {
      exception : error
    };
    this.appInsights.trackException(exception);
  }
  private loadCustomTelemetryProperties()
  {
    this.appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(envelope => 
      {
        var item = envelope.baseData;
        item.properties = item.properties || {};
        item.properties["ApplicationPlatform"] = "WEB";
        item.properties["ApplicationName"] = "test";
        item.properties["roleName"] = "front";
        // Filter out logs with 2xx and 3xx responses
        if (item && item.responseCode) {
          const responseCode = parseInt(item.responseCode);
          if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 400) {
            // Discard logs with 2xx and 3xx responses
            return ;
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
  private createRouterSubscription()
  {
    this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
      this.logPageView(null, event.urlAfterRedirects);
    });
  }
}
```

My doubt is how to use properties in envelope.baseData or envelope.data ? how to set them ?
and how to avoid send them ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you should return `false` to signal that the events should be discarded.

```js
          if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 400) {
            // Discard logs with 2xx and 3xx responses
            return false;
          }
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#javascript-web-applications

Comment: thanks @Jos, but  even with a return boolean it always send telemetry

  let filteringFunction = (envelope) => {
      // Filter out logs with 2xx and 3xx responses
      if (envelope.data && envelope.data.responseCode) {
        const responseCode = parseInt(envelope.data.responseCode);
        if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 400) {
          // Discard logs with 2xx and 3xx responses
          return false ;
        }
      }
      return true;
    };

    this.appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(filteringFunction);

Comment: :-( then I would suggest to just use a basic test app and strip all logic down to the minimum, and see if that bubbles up the issue